# Googlesheets ImportRange with Randbetween issues

Tags: google-sheets, random, google-sheets-formula

I've got a sheet (GoogleSheet#1) that runs some random numbers, creates a few filtered rows, and then randomly selects a value from that row using =RandBetween.

My issue is that I have another sheet (GoogleSheet#2), which uses =ImportRange(); this sheet pulls from GoogleSheet#1. It is not pulling the values shown. I'd guess that it's rerunning all of the RandBetween a second time before pulling...I don't know what else it could be. Why is this occurring, and what might I be able to do to pull the data that my GoogleSheet#1 is actually generating?

Comment: `I'd guess that it's rerunning all of the RandBetween a second time before pulling` I'd guess that you are right.

Comment: There's probably not a good answer for you besides randbetween as volatile, and likely doesn't work with a calc-heavy formula like import range I think I experimented with this once trying to make some board game on google sheets. Try hard-coding your values and. Assuming everything performs fine when numbers aren't random, then you have some calculation order of operations to address. You could address it using appscripts  (that's what I did) to have it create some random values as values so it's not constantly recalculating.